# Event not working on dynamically created element

Tags: ajax, dynamic, event-handling, jquery

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the mouseover event won't work with the .on handler with a dynamically created element from ajax. The only thing that seems to work is the code with .live but I understand that it is deprecated.

```
$(".dropdown ul li").live("mouseover", function() {
alert('mouseover works');
});
```

However, when I try using .on, it will not work - no matter what variations I try (document.ready, .mouseover, etc etc)

```
$(".dropdown ul li").on("mouseover", function() {
alert('mouseover works');
});
```

The event handlers are at the bottom of the code, so they are executed last. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: The `.on()` syntax that you show is _not_ equivalent to `.live()` or `.delegate()`. The jQuery [doco for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) tells you how to convert to use `.on()` or `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `.on` for newly generated elements with **dynamic event delegation**  http://api.jquery.com/on/ - where your main selector is an existent  **static parent**:

```
$(".static-parent").on("event1 event2", ".dynamic-child", function() {
```

or in your case:

```
$(".dropdown").on("mouseover", "li", function() {
   alert('mouseover works!!!!!!!!!');
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Also make sure to use a **DOM ready** function

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM is now ready and $ alias secured

    $(".dropdown").on("mouseover", "li", function() {
       alert('mouseover works!!!!!!!!!');
    });

});
```

Comment: alert('no it doesn't); :((( was really hoping it would! no event handlers (.click, .on, .delegate) seem to be working except .live! not sure what's going on

Comment: @7ch5 What jQuery version you use?

Comment: Still trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Your answer is so beautifully laid out that it's a shame it still doesn't work! :( If it makes a difference, the code is for a search bar where I type things in and the query is the list item that is echoed out. Every other event handler (eg for the actual searchbox (keyup, blur, etc)) works except for this dynamically created element.

Comment: How does this demo have any relations with the Question?

Comment: A ul with list items is supposed to show up - but I didn't realize that I couldn't access the data through another site on jsfiddle so it didn't show up as anticipated.. (if you click on the link then you will see the ul & list items that get dynamically created. Thanks so much for trying but I think we'll just sleep on it and see if we can figure it out in the morning.

Comment: Reedited my answer and added a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/MAL7a/ . Just remove `ul` from `$(".dropdown")` cause that `ul` is also dynamically generated so not a valid element. Now I think I understand. I thought that you create dynamically just the `li` elements!