# Click function not working on div class created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, jquery-events

I am unsure as to how to approach this problem.

I have some buttons made in the HTML with some data attributes added to them. These buttons have a class called `roleBtn` which will call my jQuery `roleBtnClicked` function and grab the variables in the HTML's data attributes.

```
$(".roleBtn").click(roleBtnClicked);

function roleBtnClicked(event){
    reg.roleName  = $(this).html();           /* Get role name: Actor */
    reg.blueBtn   = $(this).data('blue');     /* Get blue-btn-1 */
    reg.the_Num   = $(this).data('num');      /* Get the number */
    reg.modal_ID  = $(this).data('modal');    /* Get modal-1 */
```

Now using this information, after the `roleBtn` is clicked a modal window will come up, I then have a `doneButton` which will close the modal window and use the variables from the data attributes to then generate new HTML on the fly. This new HTML will contain a button with the class of `blueBtn`.

My problem is that my click function for `blueBtn` won't work on a blue button that was created on the fly. It will work on a div that already has the class `blueBtn` before hand, but doesn't work if it was created on the fly.

Do you know a workaround to this? Or am I missing something simple?

After the `doneButton` is clicked I have another function that creates the new HTML including the blueBtns on the fly:

```
$('.selected_row .choices-col-left').append('<div class="blueBtn-holder" id="blueBtnHolder-'+theNum+'"><div class="blueBtn" id="'+blueBtn+'" row="'+rowName+'" modal="'+modal_ID+'" num="'+theNum+'">'+roleName+'</div></div>');
```

My blue button click function which doesn't work

```
$(".blueBtn").click(blueBtnClicked);

function blueBtnClicked(event){
    alert("Where are you blueBtn on the fly?");
    console.log("Where are you blueBtn on the fly?");
};
```

Comment: https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_frPF490PF490&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=fr&rlz=1C1ASUT_frPF490PF490&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20click%20function%20not%20working%20on%20div%20class%20created%20on%20the%20fly&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=d5d763d789c53203&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.d2k&biw=1366&bih=667

Comment: Dynamic elements will need the delegated version of on(), a search would have given you a gazillion answers to this question ?

Comment: (O.T.) When you enter the [jQuery] tag asking a Q there should be a popup saying: "Hey you! Did you knew about the cool `.on()` method?" :) we really miss that feature!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288516/jquery-mouseover-not-working-with-dynamically-created-element and other 100 Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:-
You need Event delegation for dynamically created elements using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(".selected_row").on('click', '.blueBtn', blueBtnClicked);

function blueBtnClicked(event){
    alert("Where are you blueBtn on the fly?");
    console.log("Where are you blueBtn on the fly?");
};
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YbhDU/)

When you just bind a click event, it will be only bound to the existing DOM elements, so you want to bind the event to the parent element  and later any elements you add with the same selector with that container will have the event available by delegation.

> *From Jquery Docs*
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Thanks! I did search for this, but kept finding questions about semi-similar situations, but not exactly what I was trying to do. Another 10 mins before I can check your answer :)

Comment: No problem , Have added a demo too, incase you want to refer.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have to reassign event handlers for newly created items.

A better approach would be using `.on` on the container object, and then specify the child objects that should respond to the clicks:

```
$(".container").on('click', '.blueBtn', blueBtnClicked);
```

This way even if you ad objects on the fly, they will still respond. This is actually a lot more efficient way of handling that, because you only create one event handler as oppose to many. This is actually called *event delegation*.

Remember that when you do `$(selector).click`, you're telling jQuery to find all elements matching `selector` and assign the specific "click handler" to them. This does not happen again when you create new objects, because you're not telling jQuery to handle every future object as well (jQuery will not be aware of you adding a new button and will not assign a handler to it).