# jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have the feeling that my problem is something very stupid, but I couldn't fix it. I have two divs in one container, and one of them is hidden by default. When the mouse is over the parent div I want to show the hidden div with a `slideDown` and hide the other one. It works perfectly when I move the mouse from upside the div to bottom, but if I move the mouse from the bottom it slides up and down for a while. Here I have a fiddle:

[EDIT]

I forgot to say that I need this to work with dynamically created divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/7gva4fad/

```js
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.msg').hide();
        jQuery(this).find('.conv').slideDown(300);        
    }
}, ".tooltip");

jQuery(document).on({
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.conv').slideUp(300);
        jQuery(this).find('.msg').show();
    }
}, ".tooltip");
```

```css
.tooltip{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.conv{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="conv">Hello again</div>
    <div class="msg">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Any idea is fully appreciated.

Comment: it is generally considerate to include the relevant code in the body of your message as well as to provide a jsfiddle link. this ensures that your question remains relevant in the future even if your code is no longer hosted on jsfiddle.

Comment: When you hover over the element it immediately hides `.msg` and the parent container (`.tooltip`) suddenly gets a height of 0 which means the mouse leaves the element and it triggers the leave function.

Comment: @JRulle I got what you said, and added an static height to the `.tooltip` div, but it keeps sliding up and down. Did I miss something else? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288516/jquery-mouseover-not-working-with-dynamically-created-element/11288527#11288527 (just instead of mouseover use *mouseenter*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first hide the the `.msg` DIV the `mouseleave` event is called, because, the `.tooltip` DIV has height 0.

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.msg').stop(false, true).slideUp(300);
        jQuery(this).find('.conv').stop(false, true).slideDown(300);        
    }
}, ".tooltip");

jQuery(document).on({
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.conv').stop(false, true).slideUp(300);
        jQuery(this).find('.msg').stop(false, true).slideDown(300);
    }
}, ".tooltip");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7gva4fad/2/

Comment: I ended using your solution because it fits better to my project (: and couldn't use `on({hover` and I needed it because my divs are dynamically created. Your answer works perfect, thank you (:

Comment: I just changed your solution as less as necessary ;) but who gave me -1 and why?

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.tooltip').hover(function() {
        $('.msg, .conv', this).stop().slideToggle();
    });
   
});
```

```css
.tooltip{
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.conv{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="conv">Hello again</div>
    <div class="msg">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfect (:, just a question, what's the difference between `hover` and `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`? Which one is better? Thank you so much (:

Comment: @Cassandra `.hover()` method (N.B: *not* the `.on('hover'...)`!) is the exact *replica* of both *.on* `mouseenter mouseleave` event listeners.

Comment: similarly, you can use `$(this).bind('mouseenter', 'mouseleave')`, pretty sure there's no real difference there.

Comment: i'm saying binding to mouseenter and mouseleave is the same thing as binding to hover: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ hover is a shorthand for both events, and you can `.bind()` to both alternatively, if you dont like passing handlers to `.hover()`, AFAIK. Sorry to contradict you there buddy. relax.